# how can I use two variables inside a sumproduct formula in vba?

Tags: vba, variables, syntax, formula, sumproduct

I have two tables and three variables as below in one sheet

1. LastSize for the number of last column of my first table
2. LastMat for the number of last column of my second table
3. LastProduct for the number of last row of my first and second table (both are equal)

I want to use them in a sumproduct function in VBA but I don't know how to write it.

To help you get my problem:

- to_char is a function that turn the number of a column to its word (like: to_char(3) is D)
- I is a counter for my loop

> ```
> "=sumnproduct("LastSize"5:"LastSize""LastProduct" , "to_char(I)"5:"to_char(I)""LastProduct")
> ```

Answer (score 1):

VBA doesn't have a `SUMPRODUCT` function. Therefore you must use VBA's `WorksheetFunction` method to call Excel's function by that name. This is the syntax.

```
Dim MyResult As Double
MyResult = WorksheetFunction.Sumproduct([Arg1],[Arg2],[Arg3],[etc])
```

Excel requires each argument to be a range, like `=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A1,C2:C15,F2:F15, [etc])` You can create these ranges in whatever way VBA puts at your disposal. Any of these methods will do fine.

```
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim Rng2 As Range
Dim Rng3 As Range
Set Rng1 = Range("A2:A15")
Set Rng2 = Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(15, 3))
Set Rng3 = Range(Cells(2, "F"), Cells(15, "F))

MyResult = WorksheetFunction.Sumproduct(Rng1, Rng2, Rng3)
```

Of course any or all of the parameters specifying a range can be a variable.

```
Dim A As String, B As String
A = Cells(1, 1).Value         ' the cell holds a cell or range address or column ID
B = Cells(1, 2). Value
Set Rng1 = Range(A)
Set Rng2 = Range(Cells(2, A), Cells(15, B))
Set Rng3 = Range(Range(A), Range(B))

' or
Dim R As Long, C As Long
R = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
C = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set Rng1 = Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(R, C))
```

Note the syntax for defining a cell: `Cells([Row], [Column])`. [Row] must always be a number but [Column] can be a number or a valid ID (which is a string). Strings are hard to force into addresses, slower to execute because Excel must convert them to numbers, and impossible to calculate. Therefore you are well advised to prefer numbers for both rows and columns. The recommended data type for this kind of numbers is `Long`.

Comment: yeah youre right
but i have another issue
how can i sen you my code? and explain my problem
its only 12 line but i cant send it here